# Private Route Conditional Operator in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-router, jsx

Seems like a trivial issue.

I have an app, where people can subscribe through "stripe". Would like to give access to a few URLs based on subscription, otherwise taking them back to the "profile" page.

A couple of things are not working.

1. Firebase query to get **subscription** is not giving results on the subscription. Somehow the **onSnapShot** does not fetch anything. Probably since UID is null at the start of rendering of page.
2. Conditional operator on  is not working. Not sure what the problem is on this one.

```
function PaidRoutes(props) {


  const [subscription, setSubscription] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsub = auth.onAuthStateChanged((authObject) => {
      unsub();
      if (authObject) {
        setLoading(true);
        const uid = auth.currentUser?.uid;
        console.log('UID ==>', uid);
        let docRef = query(collection(db, 'customers', uid, 'subscription'));
        console.log('DOC REF ==> ', docRef);
        onSnapshot(docRef, (snap) => {
          snap.forEach((doc) => {
            console.log('Role of Subscription', doc.data().role);
            setSubscription(doc.data().role);
          });
        });
      } else {
        console.log('not logged in');
        setLoading(false);
      }
    });
    return () => {
      unsub();
    };
  }, []);



  return (
    <Route
      {...props}
      render={(props) =>
        subscription ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to='/profileScreen' />
        )
      }
    />
  );
```

Thanks Drew for comment. The installed version of **react-router-dom** is **5.2.0**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue(s)

Potential issues I see in the `PaidRoute` code:

1. The unsubscribe function is called in the auth state handler, this might allow the auth check to work once on an initial auth change, but then will unsubscribe itself and stop working until the component remounts.
2. The `loading` state is initially `false` so any check based on it on the initial render won't do what you want. The `loading` also isn't used to hold off on the conditional rendering.
3. The `subscription` state is initially an empty array which is still truthy, so the conditional logic checking it will likely allow access to the protected route anyway, regardless of any auth status.

## Solution

1. Don't unsubscribe from the auth change listener in the callback.
2. Start with `loading` initially true to handle the initial render cycle. Conditionally render null or some loading indicator.
3. Start with null `subscription` state.

Code:

```
function PaidRoutes(props) {
  const [subscription, setSubscription] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((authObject) => {
      if (authObject) {
        setLoading(true);
        const uid = auth.currentUser?.uid;
        console.log('UID ==>', uid);
        const docRef = query(collection(db, 'customers', uid, 'subscription'));
        console.log('DOC REF ==> ', docRef);
        onSnapshot(docRef, (snap) => {
          snap.forEach((doc) => {
            console.log('Role of Subscription', doc.data().role);
            setSubscription(doc.data().role);
          });
        });
      } else {
        console.log('not logged in');
        setSubscription(null); // <-- reset auth state
      }
      setLoading(false); // <-- clear loading state outside if-else
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);

  if (loading) {
    return null; // or loading indicator, spinner, etc...
  }

  return subscription ? (
    <Route {...props} />
  ) : (
    <Redirect to='/profileScreen' />
  );
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm Drew. However, a small issue. Even the folks , who have subscribed are not able to route to the route they are supposed to go.        

I will say your response on the ReactJS are legendary and learned a lot from just your response.

Comment: Seems like "setSubscription" is not getting assigned after fetching data from firebase. Probably the culprit is this part of code.         onSnapshot(docRef, (snap) => {
          console.log('SNAP ===>', snap);
          snap.forEach((doc) => {
            console.log('Role of Subscription ==> ', doc.data().role);
            setSubscription(doc.data().role);
          });
        });

Comment: @LonelySoul Can you confirm the installed version of `react-router-dom` and edit your question to share how you are trying to access the the protected routes? About the inner `setSubscription` code, I also thought it to be a little suspect. It doesn't seem like it needs to be a subscription, but rather just a get, as in query the firebase collection once. What you do from there depends on the "snapshot" value. Is it really *just* the role that needs to be saved into local state? What is this inner "snapshot" value that is `forEach`'d over?

Comment: Thanks @Drew.. just updated question with version of React-router-dom. It's 5.2.0. Is it possible to use "class" or "functional" component to query the firebase once user id becomes available without using **onAuthStateChanged**. The **role** value inside onSnapshot is just a string such as "basic" or "premium". Hope it helps

Comment: @LonelySoul I think ideally you'd want to move this `onAuthStateChanged` effect higher in the ReactTree, like `App` or an auth context and hold the auth state there. The role probably also only needs to be fetched once. Use one of the firebase `get()` calls for this when the auth state changes and a user is logged in. The custom route component only needs to check the current authentication state and role for the current user, it likely doesn't need to query firebase each time a user accesses a protected route.